# SQL: how do I find if the contents of a varchar column are numeric?

Tags: sql, oracle

One of the columns in my table is a varchar that is supposed to contain only numeric values (I can't change the definition to a number column). Thus my SQL query:

```
select to_number(col1) from tbl1 where ...
```

fails because for some row the contents of the column are not numeric.

What's a `select` query I can use to find these rows ?

I'm using an Oracle database

I'm looking for something like a `is_number` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no native "isnumeric" function in oracle, but this link shows you how to make one: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/o44asktom-089519.html

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isnumeric(p_string in varchar2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
    l_number number;
BEGIN
    l_number := p_string;
    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
END;
/
```

Comment: This does not link not to an article/solution anymore.

Comment: An example of why answers should actually answer the question, not provide links to the answer. The original article is available from the Wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20100701194827/http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/04-jul/o44asktom.html

Answer (score 4):

I don't disagree that the best solution is to follow Tom Kyte's examples others have linked to already.  However, if you just need something that is SQL only because you unfortunately do not have the relationship with your DBA to add pl/sql functions to your schema you could possibly leverage regular expressions to meet a basic need.  Example:

```
select '234', REGEXP_SUBSTR('234','^\d*\.{0,1}\d+$') from dual
union all
select 'abc', REGEXP_SUBSTR('abc','^\d*\.{0,1}\d+$') from dual
union all
select '234234abc', REGEXP_SUBSTR('234234abc','^\d*\.{0,1}\d+$') from dual
union all
select '100.4',  REGEXP_SUBSTR('100.4','^\d*\.{0,1}\d+$') from dual
union all
select '-100.4',  REGEXP_SUBSTR('-100.4','^\d*\.{0,1}\d+$') from dual
union all
select '',  REGEXP_SUBSTR('','^\d*\.{0,1}\d+$') from dual
```

Below is the output of the above:

```
INPUT      RESULT
234        234
abc        -
234234abc  -
100.4      100.4
-100.4     -
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1794145000346577404

Answer (score 1):

You may need to decide for yourself what is numeric.
Oracle will happily convert character strings in scientific notation (eg '1e10') to numbers, but it will baulk at something like '1,000' (because of the comma).

Comment: The decimal separator depends on the nls-settings: NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS