# Oracle - applying the to_number function to a varchar column

Tags: oracle

I want to convert a varchar column into a number using the to_number function however I have some trouble understanding the order in which Oracle attempts to execute my SQL.

The statement looks like this;

```
select * from table where column is not null and to_number(column, '999.9') > 20
```

When Oracle executes this it throws an invalid number exception. I understand that Oracle optimized the SQL statement using some kind of relational algebraic formula however can someone tell me how I can safely use the to_number operator to achieve my goal?

Comment: You have some non-null values in the column that can't be converted to a number

Comment: why are non-null values a problem?

Comment: because the nulls are taken care of by `is not null` (and I think to_number will also not choke on them, but just pass through the null)

Comment: @linuxlewis - What do you want `TO_NUMBER('this is not a number', '999.9')` to return?

Comment: the column contains values 1-100 however the column type is a varchar. My goal is to convert the data so i can apply mathematical operations to the values in it

Comment: Well, it's fairly obvious that it doesn't contain only values from 1 to 100.

Comment: can you double-check that? from the error, it looks like you have some invalid data.

Comment: could be just leading or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can someone tell me how I can safely use the to_number operator to achieve my goal?

Unfortunately, you'll have to [first filter out the rows with non-numerical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080178/sql-how-do-i-find-if-the-contents-of-a-varchar-column-are-numeric?rq=1) somehow before you apply `to_number`. The conversion function itself is "not safe", if you will, it will crash the whole query on a single invalid input.