# Throwing Invalid number error in Oracle while executing OR

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

My Table structures are..

```
A_TEXT(ID number,name varchar2)
POLICY_INFO (PI_ID number,relation_id varchar2)
```

I have query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM A_TEXT A  WHERE   a.name  = 'test' OR  a.ID IN 
            (SELECT  TO_NUMBER(RELATION_ID )
             FROM POLICY_INFO 
             )
```

When I try to execute query I got Invalid Number exception. If you modified query little bit  Like  :

```
SELECT * FROM A_TEXT A  WHERE a.name  = 'test' OR  TO_CHAR(a.ID) IN 
           (SELECT  RELATION_ID
             FROM POLICY_INFO 
             )
```

It executes well.

Comment: visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740055/oracle-applying-the-to-number-function-to-a-varchar-column)

Comment: May be the value of **RELATION_ID** is a character.

Comment: Never store numbers in varchar columns. If `policy_info.relation_id` does reference `a_text.id` then make `relation_id` a number and create a foreign key constraint.

Comment: @user2818560 check this out sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2aabd/4 Can you check the number format of database or post the result of SELECT TO_NUMBER(RELATION_ID) FROM POLICY_INFO;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason is that the column `RELATION_ID` contains non numeric characters `(Anything apart from 0-9, NULL)`

Remember that all `NUMBER`'s can be converted into `VARCHAR` and not the vice versa.

To check the column RELATION_ID use this below function and validate your non numeric strings.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isnumeric(p_string in varchar2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
    l_number number;
BEGIN
    l_number := p_string;
    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
END;
/
```

**FOLLOW UP:**

```
WITH POLICY_INFO
    AS (SELECT
             1 AS PI_ID,
             '1' AS RELATION_ID
        FROM
             DUAL),
    A_TEXT
    AS (SELECT
             1 AS ID,
             'testA' AS NAME
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             2 AS ID,
             'test' AS NAME
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      *
FROM
      A_TEXT A
WHERE
      A.NAME = 'test'
      OR A.ID IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER ( RELATION_ID ) FROM POLICY_INFO);
```

This works fine. Please check this. If you still face issue, let us know the complete dataset

Comment: I'd say it's not a *possible* reason, but it's most definitely the reason for the error.

Comment: no column RELATION_ID does not have any non numeric characters. Only numbers are stored in that column

Comment: Please post your dataset as INSERT statments

Comment: insert into POLICY_INFO (1,'1');
insert into A_TEXT(1,'testA');
insert into A_TEXT(2,'test');

Answer (score 0):

Either you have non-numbers in your database column, or you have a number format problem. To debug this situation, you can do this (a slight variation of @realspirituals answer):

```
declare
  l_dummy number;
begin
  for cur in (select relation_id from policy_info)
  loop
     begin
        l_dummy := to_number(cur.relation_id);
     exception
        when others then dbms_output.put_line(cur.relation_id);
     end;
  end loop;
end;
```

This will print all offending values from policy_info.relation_id;